# Pack consecutive duplicate of item from a list into a list of lists & based on index position of that consecutive duplicates, do same for another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists ("status" and "volt"). **I want to read "status" list and Pack consecutive duplicates of a particular item from that list into a list of lists. Then read the 2nd list ("volt") and based on the index position of consecutive duplicates from the 1st list ("status"), pack or group item from the 2nd list ("volt") into a list of lists.**
Please help me on this, the code I have tried is given below:

Please note: items in lists "status" and "volt", are separated with spaces to show the group I want to create and put them in another list.

```
Packed_status = []
Packed_volt = []
status = [1, 1, 1, 1,   0, 0, 0,     1, 1,     0, 0,     1, 1, 1,     0, 0, 0,     1, 1,     0]
volt = [2, 3, 4, 5,     1, 3, 7,     2, 6,     5, 3,     3, 8, 4,     9, 5, 3,     6, 2,     7]

for i in range(0, len(status), 1):
    if status[i] == 0:
        Packed_status.append(status[i])
        Packed_volt.append(volt[i])
print Packed_status
print Packed_volt
```

The Output I am getting is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 3, 7, 5, 3, 9, 5, 3, 7]
```

The Output I need is:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
[[1, 3, 7], [5, 3], [9, 5, 3], [7]]
```

Items chosen for 2nd list grouping should be exactly same as the index position of the 1st list packing or grouping (for consecutive duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value in list is store as type of `int`. so space is not work for divide the list. if you still want answer. you can find by using value of list `0` and `1`.

Try this :

```
Packed_status = []
Packed_volt = []
status = [1, 1, 1, 1,   0, 0, 0,     1, 1,     0, 0,     1, 1, 1,     0, 0, 0,     1, 1,     0]
volt = [2, 3, 4, 5,     1, 3, 7,     2, 6,     5, 3,     3, 8, 4,     9, 5, 3,     6, 2,     7]

count = 0
temp_volt = []
temp_status = []
for i in range(0, len(status), 1):
    if status[i] == 0:
        temp_status.append(status[i])
        temp_volt.append(volt[i])
        count = 1
    else:
        if count == 1:
            Packed_status.append(temp_status)
            Packed_volt.append(temp_volt)
            temp_volt = []
            temp_status =[]
            count = 0
if count == 1:
    Packed_status.append(temp_status)
    Packed_volt.append(temp_volt)
print Packed_status
print Packed_volt
```

Output :

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
[[1, 3, 7], [5, 3], [9, 5, 3], [7]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bhargav Desai, I appreciate your help.

Comment: If it works, check it as the answer plz. Hit the check between the two arrows.

Comment: it is working fine Mr. @Bhargav Desai, Thanks a lot. However, my reputation is not enough to cast my vote. is there any other I can do anything? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You does not need reputation to check it as answer or for cast a vote.